# ping: Ping one resource but response comes from another

Tags: ping

I can't understand why I see this

`$ ping aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa
PING aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa (aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa) 56(84) bytes of data.
From bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb icmp_seq=1 Time to live exceeded
From bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb icmp_seq=2 Time to live exceeded
From bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb icmp_seq=3 Time to live exceeded`

There bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb  from my ISP range.

Comment: [When Are ICMP Redirects Sent?](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/routing-information-protocol-rip/13714-43.html)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a ping from windows. Given that even routers can ping using the command ping, from where are you pinging? We need a bit more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you ping (well any network traffic really) you go across a number of 'hops'. Each hop reduces the TTL you will see in your ping results (of a successful ping) if this TTL reaches 0 the TTL will be exceeded such as what your seeing in your results.

This is normally caused by a loop in the network so the response you are getting is from the last hop that it got too before the TTL hit 0.

If your run a tracert to that location you can see the last hop the trace hits before it fails/loops.